# How can i rebuild vhost on cPanel?

Tags: nginx, cpanel

I haven't cPanel License. I created new user on SSH. But **i need rebuild vhost nginx** How can i do it?

Summary: I need rebuild nginx vhost without cPanel.

**I bought cPanel licence.**

Answer (score 0):

You can not rebuild it through command line, You need to do it with WHM.

Answer (score 0):

What type of nginx plugins are you using on cPanel/WHM server? Its nginxadmin (the free one) or the cpnginx (commercial one)?